# Modal stays on screen or Does not appear when clicking <a> element

Tags: css, modal-dialog

```
 <div class="lotion-container">
  <div class="lotion-sub">
    <img src="images/item1.png" alt="">
    <h5>THE RITUAL OF SAKURA</h5>
    <h4>Cherry Blossom Hand Lotion</h4>
    <p>Body lotion, 70ml</p>
    <p>$12.50</p>
    <a href="#lotion1">ADD TO BAG</a>
  </div>
  <div class="lotion-sub">
    <img src="images/item2.png" alt="">
    <h5>THE RITUAL OF AYURVEDA</h5>
    <h4>Himalaya Honey body cream</h4>
    <p>Body lotion, 70ml</p>
    <p>$7.50</p>
    <a href="#lotion2">ADD TO BAG</a>
  </div>
  <div class="lotion-sub">
    <img src="images/item3.png" alt="">
    <h5>THE RITUAL OF SAKURA</h5>
    <h4>Organic rice miilk body cream</h4>
    <p>Body lotion, 70ml</p>
    <p>$7.50</p>
    <a href="#lotion3">ADD TO BAG</a>
  </div>
  <div id="lotion1" class="L1">
      <div class="info1">
      <h4>IT'S IN THE BAG!</h4>
      <hr>
      <img src="images/item1.png" alt="">
       <h5>The RITUAL OF SAKURA</h5>
       <h3>Cherry Blosson Hand Lotion</h3>
       <p>Body lotion, 70ml</p>
       <h5>$12.50</h5>
       <br>
       <p>Mix & Match 3/$33</p>
        <p>Nurture and comfort skin from top to toe with The Ritual of Sakura Body Cream from
          Rituals.</p>
          <hr>
          <a href ="#"class="CS1">CONTINUE SHOPPING</a>
          <a href="#"class="clos1">X</a>
          </div>
  </div>
```

So I'm trying to make a popup modal the issue arises when I go to CSS and try and change the opacity and make the modal context only appear when the user presses the add to bag link so can anyone give me advice or a helping hand on where I went wrong on the code.
Using CSS create a modal that pops up when person wants to click on add to bag.

Comment: you're going to need some javascript to achieve a working shopping cart functionality... or you could try something like this: https://codepen.io/timothylong/pen/HhAer , but ultimately you'll need js to allow for multiple products in the cart

Comment: JS is needed. There's plenty of options on GitHub https://github.com/search?l=JavaScript&q=modal&type=Repositories

I prefer accessible modals, these are couple of good modals I have tried: https://github.com/HugoGiraudel/a11y-dialog https://github.com/jsor/lity

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for the helpful comments I Ended up using javascript and getting everything to work.